# Basic C help: Function declarations

Tags: c

I just started learning C and am not sure what the issue is here.

EDIT

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

struct student {
    int age;
    char gender;
    char course[30];
};

defineNewStudent("Jarryd", 24, 'M', "Software Engineering");

return 0;
}

void defineNewStudent(char studentName[20], int age, char gender, char course[30])
{
student studentName[30];
studentName.age = age;
studentName.gender = gender;
studentName.course = course[20];

printf("%s is %d.\n Gender: %c.\n Course: %s.\n", studentName, studentName.age,  studentName.gender, studentName.course);
}
```

I have a warning

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'defineNewStudent'

I am trying to take the passed in argument and use it to name the struct, how is this done?

What is this warning about and what are the consequences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be because the struct `student` is only defined inside the function `main`. You're trying to use it in the `defineNewStudent` function, but that struct is not defined there. Define the struct at the global scope.

The warning is because you're trying to call the `defineNewStudent` function before you actually declare it, and the compiler still doesn't know about it at that point. You can declare the function before you try to use it.

```
// define the student struct at global scope
struct student
{
    int age;
    char gender;
    char course[20];
};

// declare the function (it can still be defined later)
void defineNewStudent(char studentName[20], int age, char gender, char course[20]);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   defineNewStudent("Jarryd", 24, 'M', "Software Engineering");

   return 0;
}

void defineNewStudent(char studentName[20], int age, char gender, char course[20])
{
    // you already have a variable called studentName,
    // you can't have two variables with the same name
    struct student studentData;
    studentData.age = age;
    studentData.gender = gender;
    studentData.course = course;

    printf("%s is %d.\n Gender: %c.\n Course: %s.\n", 
         studentName, 
         studentData.age, 
         studentData.gender,
         studentData.course
    );
}
```

EDIT:

to define an instance of a struct in C you need the `struct` keyword, so in the example it should be

```
struct student studentData;
studentData.age = age;
studentData.gender = gender;
studentData.course = course;
```

**If it were c++**, you could drop the `struct` keyword:

```
student studentData;
studentData.age = age;
studentData.gender = gender;
studentData.course = course;
```

optionally in C, you can typedef the struct to an alias to make it easier to define instances of it:

```
typedef struct student
{
    int age;
    char gender;
    char course[20];
} StudentStruct;

// define it like this in the function:
StudentStruct studentData;
```

Comment: Thanks.So prototyping is the same as in obj-c where methods are declared in the header file?

Comment: For interest's sake, Is there a C equivalent to "this" in java

Comment: Ok. The redeclaration of studentName is because I wanna use the argument to name the struct. If I want to access or modify the data at a later stage, I want to use the students name to access it. How would I do that in your example? thanks

Comment: C is not object oriented, so there is no equivalent to `this`.

Comment: and unfortunately, access the struct by the students name is not going to be as easy as you're hoping... it definitely won't work the way you're trying to do it. It would be a lot easier if you could do it in c++, though. C++ is object-oriented and the c++ standard library has classes to do that easily.

Comment: One more thing. Does it really require strncpy to use an argument of a string to set a value. e.g. studentData.studentName = name(some passed in string formation) gives an error incompatible types in assignment.

Comment: yes, you have to use `strcpy`. it's simple, though. `strcpy(studentData.studentName, studentName);`

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't have methods. You're trying to define a function in a function. You can't declare a function inside main().

You also have studentName declared twice inside defineNewStudent(), once as the first parameter, and you declare something with the same name inside it.

Also assigning studentName.course = course won't work. You would have to do something like

strncpy(studentName.course, course, sizeof(studentName.course));

You have to define the function before it's use. You can either move the entire thing before main which is what I would do, or you could include just it's prototype before main which here would be:

```
void defineNewStudent(char studentName[20], int age, char gender, char course[30]);
```

Comment: You can definitely have nested functions with gcc.  Now, whether or not that's a good idea is an entirely different story.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

Comment: @Carl: You can in gcc, but it's not standard C.  Or a good idea :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I agree 100%.  The OP's error message seems to indicate that his compiler *can* in fact support nested functions, though, so his question about his error and warning aren't due to that choice.

Comment: Thanks. The prototyping is nice. Student is undeclared in the defineNewStudent method. Can a structure be declared outside the main? That is overkill for strncpy, how are string arguments normally used in C? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems - nesting functions is probably a bad idea, for one.  Take `defineNewStudent()` and put it outside of `main()`.  Depending on where you put it (before or after `main()`), you may also need a function prototype before the call site in `main()`.

Also, you need to change the array parameter declarations for `defineNewStudent()` to look like `char parameterName[20]`, instead of what you have there.

You're also going to have some problems with `studentName` being the name of two different variables, with trying to copy a string using simple assignment, and with `"Software Engineering"` being too big to fit in your arrays.

And as @arsenm mentions in his answer, C doesn't have methods.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Carl. You actually have to define the function before you use it and for that either you put your function above main() or put a function prototype before main:

void defineNewStudent(char studentName[20], int age, char gender, char course[20]);

main()
...rest of code

And you will have one more problem due to the fact the parameter and a local variable of your function have same name which will give a compiler error.
Also there are functions in C and not methods(which are in JAVA/C++ etc)